# What C# class pattern should I use for mobile client / server objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, delegates, client-server

I am developing a client / server business software system using a custom HTTP based design that works similarly to CSLA.NET.  What I will be doing is creating client and server objects where client method calls get serialized in to json (using json.net) or other format and then deserialized on the server in to the mirror server version.  I am using custom attributes to mark functions and classes that can be called remotely.  If it is an instance method it will serialize the calling object as well, where as static calls obviously will just serialize the method parameters.  When the server call finishes it will respond with the method result, error state, and the new copy of the object in the case of instance calls.

I already have a test version of this running.  What I am trying to do now is figure out the best pattern to use for these client and server object.  My test version uses completely separate classes on the client and server.  While that works I would like them to be more tied together to ensure that all the properties are the same etc.

I am relatively new to C# and do not have a whole lot of experience with them, but I thought that maybe using interfaces would be the best way.  I am not 100% of the reasons for choosing interfaces vs normal class inheritance, but I can't think at the moment of any situation where I would have a use for a base class implementation so it seemed like a reasonable choice. The problem I ran in to was when I tried to do something like have a `LoadCustomers` method that would return a `List<IMyObject>`.  The client version would need to cast a `List<IMyObject>` to a `List<MyObject_Client>`.  It would error out though.  It seems that while it works with casting the classes themselves, when you do it with generics like this it doesn't work.  I think I would be able to get by casting each time I used the items in the `List` vs casting the `List` itself, but that seems messier to me.  I also worried about having properties defined in the interface like `List<IMyObject>` where technically they would accept any type of implementation of `IMyObject`, but really when I am on the client I only want `MyObject_Client` objects to be in that list.  Both of these problems seem like they would also exist if I was using simple class inheritance instead of interfaces.

So at this point I am thinking that the best option is to make it one object for both client and server.  What this means is that I would have some static context class that would maintain whether the program was using client or server objects.  Then in each method would look something like this:

```
if (MyContextObject.ObjectContext == ocClient)
{
    //Code to serialize and make call to server and return result
} else {
    //Actual business logic
}
```

or

```
if (MyContextObject.ObjectContext == ocClient)
{
    //Call to private client version of the function
} else {
    //Call to private server version of the function
}
```

I have also considered possibly using delegates that get set during the constructor depending on the context.  I am not sure if that is worth it or not partially because I am such a C# novice.  It may improve readability I guess?

Having one class would be nice from the stand point of it all being in one place and it makes it easier to facilitate client to server calls because the exact object name you want to use on the server is the same exact one that is on the client.  The problem is that isolating the client objects from the server objects has it's benefits as well.

**So my question is what pattern should I use for these client server objects?**

My concerns are:

- **Robustness / Reliability / Speed** - This will replace a real existing
  product so I don't want slow or "hacky" code)
- **Maintainability** - I want to easily be able to make updates and keep
  both client and server objects in sync.  The more help from the compiler to make sure I didn't miss something on either one of the objects the better
- **Readability** - This is part of maintainability, but it is very
  important to me that it is simple and easy to understand code that is
  going to be used by multiple developers.  By easy I mean easy for a programmer that understands the pattern we are using.
- **Time to implement** - I am coming from a horrible fat client world, but
  one of the only benefits it had was that I only had to implement one
  version of each method. Now I have two.  The easier and faster it is
  to implement each method the better.
- **Static** - I would like it to be possible to use both static and not
  static methods.  Some of the methods like LoadCustomers I would like
  to be static calls.  I tried abstract classes I think and ran in to
  problems when the method was static.
- **Platforms** - I HAVE to support running the client AND server on every
  version of Windows start with Windows XP.  I also must also be able
  to support 3rd party client implementations on any platform (web or
  desktop or mobile).  We provide the main desktop app to use the
  software right now, but we want to be able to start interfacing with
  handheld devices (w/ barcode scanners) using html based clients we
  write.  Also, today 3rd parties will write to our database directly so in
  the future I want to be able to provide them with a safe API to use
  to discourage them from destroying our customer's data because they don't
  know what they are doing :D

Comment: `using interfaces would be the best way. I am not 100% of the reasons for choosing interfaces vs normal class inheritance`.  I'm not the most brilliant programmer in the world, but, I don't think interfaces **versus** class inheritance is the right way to think about it.  They serve two difference purposes.

Comment: Have you ruled out more service-oriented architecture, where clients are "thinner" and rely on server-side "services"?

Comment: @Ek0nomik Yea I am probably thinking about them wrong.  I just knew they would help me enforce the property and method signatures of the classes and didn't have a base class implementation which I am not sure that I need.  I may want a generic base class for all of the objects at some point, but I don't think there is any common code between the server and the client that will be needed.  Now that I think about it though there could be stuff like validation code that you might want both the client and server to have direct access to instead of doing a remote call.

Comment: @G.Stoynev I am a noob still designing with Delphi 5 (think 1999 technology) so am not well versed in a lot of the newer technologies and design architectures.  On wikipedia I see WCF in that list.  I barely understand anything of it, but I assumed that the communications it performed couldn't be implemented in a javascript client and I have never got it to work.  I am implementing the client and server as windows apps (can't require IIS or Windows Server).  But I do want it to be possible for 3rd parties to easily implement client objects on any platform that can do http.

Comment: @G.Stoynev As far as "thinner" goes though, that is one of the main goals here.  Today my life consists of maintaining Win32 screens where all the business logic is in the screens itself and it is a rat's nest to maintain.  I definitely want to separate gui from business logic and client from server where the client only cares about getting the data to the screen and telling the server what you want it to do for you.  I forgot to mention I also have to support XP.

Comment: @Fyndor - You mention WCF as a possibility. There are also other network libraries available that can meet all of your concerns, particularly time to implement. Checkout http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/ and http://www.networkcomms.net. I'm a developer for NetworkComms.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but based on the comments we exchanged, and trying to stay away from expressing opinions, I'll list two possible routes - both vehicles for delivering a service-oriented client-server solution:

1. REST-style architecture for the client-server communication. REST is tightly coupled with HTTP (and its verbs). Believers think that the RESTfull paradigm is completely sufficient and anything is possible if you design it correctly :-) (statement based on all the passionate presentations, workshop sessions, blogs and forum posts that I've seen)
2. You mention WCF. It is a viable option. WCF will give you more choices at any level of the application development, compared to REST, but with the added complexity.

I should add, that in my opinion the value of CSLA and the OOP design that you're mentioning becomes more valuable if you need to tier your server side of the application. The framework could be used out of the box, or as a case study learning tool for various problem/solution pairs: business rule definition/enforcement, cross-boundary method invocations, data layer design, etc. I would find it very restrictive, if CSLA or similar style implementation is imposed on clients - especially if you're targeting native mobile platforms, or as your question suggests. third-party client implementations.

Comment: I don't know if I want to go full REST.  I want a stateless server.  But I don't know if I want to worry about URLifying my objects and their ID keys or worry about the HTTP verbs.  I am thinking I will have all calls go to myserver_ip_address:port/api/ and be HTTP POST requests.  For instance, instead of using HTTP DELETE I would rather allow myself flexibility by making it a call to any number of Delete methods on the objects themselves.

Comment: I need to really study up on WCF.  Until I do I don't know if I can say whether or not I can make it work for my needs.

Comment: As far as CSLA goes I agree it is too restrictive.  What I am trying to pull off I think feels more natural OOP-wise.  In CSLA if you weren't writing a Load, Save, or Delete method on your business object, it seemed like you had to create a command class for each method.  That seems excessive. I worry that what I am trying to accomplish might not be fast at scale, but I won't know that for sure until I get some tests going with large DBs.

Comment: Found this bookmarked.  So I wrote my own client server framework.  It was pretty cool, but in the end I went with WCF since it was more standard.  It achieves everything I need whether I knew it or not previously is a different matter :D